# Series expansion of $ \frac{x}{\ln (1+x)}$

Tags: power-series

What are coefficients in the expansion of series for

$$ \frac{x}{\ln (1+x)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n \frac{x^n}{n!}?$$

Do they have a name?

Comment: A series around what point? A Taylor series? A Laurent series?

Comment: @vonbrand thanks for edit.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+of+x%2Fln%281%2Bx%29

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering, if Bernoulli numbers have applications and name from exponential ( $ \frac{x}{e^x-1} $) ,  log base would also have one name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Relations_with_the_reciprocal_logarithm), that
$$
\frac{z}{\ln(1-z)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_nz^n, \quad |z|<1,
$$
where the coefficients, $C_n$ are called Gregory coefficients. They can by calculated by the following recursion for all $n \geq 0$. From equations:
$$
C_0 = -1,\quad \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{C_k}{n+1-k} = 0,\quad n=1,2,3,\ldots
$$
If we use the $z=-x$ substituion, we get
$$
-\frac{x}{\ln(1+x)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nC_nx^n, \quad |x|<1.
$$
The first few Gregory coefficients are:
$$
-1,\frac12, \frac{1}{12}, \frac{1}{24}, \frac{19}{720},\frac{3}{160},\frac{863}{60480},\frac{275}{24192},\frac{33953}{3628800},\dots
$$

Answer (score 2):

One may observe that, by the binomial theorem,
$$
(1+x)^t=1+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\prod _{k=0}^{n-1} (t-k)}{n!}x^n, \quad|x|<1, \tag1
$$ then, integrating with respect to $t$ from $t=0$ to $t=1$, one gets
$$
\frac{x}{\ln(1+x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
with

> $$
> A_0=1,\quad A_n=\int_0^1 t(t-1)(t-2)\cdots(t-n+1)\:dt, \quad n \geq1.
> $$